# After updating my oculus quest 2 i cant move my hand in my unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

After updating my meta quest 2 I cant move my hands in my unity project
I changed nothing to the project since the last time I tested it(when I could still move around)
and after my oculus quest 2 updated I suddenly couldn't move my arms in my unity project does anyone know what the problem could be and maybe how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve it by going to the project settings and going to xr plug-in management and chaging the openxr to oculus